# Code mandelbrot set

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou estudando um código específico do conjunto de mandelbrot (equação com números complexos) com foco em programação orientada a objeto. Entretanto, há uma parte específica que não entendi do código, conforme abaixo:

---

```
columns = 2000

rows = 2000

result = numpy.zeros([rows, columns])

for row_index, Re in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-2, 1, num=rows)):

   for column_index, Im in enumerate (numpy.linspace(-1, 1, num=columns)):

        result[row_index, column_index] = mset(Re, Im, 200)
```

---

Abaixo, segue o código completo:

```
import numpy

from numba import autojit

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@autojit

def mset (Re, Im, max_inter):

        c = complex (Re, Im)
        z = 0

        for i in range (max_inter):
            z = z*z + c
            if (z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag) >= 4:
                return i
        return max_inter
columns = 2000

rows = 2000

result = numpy.zeros([rows, columns])

for row_index, Re in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-2, 1, num=rows)):

    for column_index, Im in enumerate (numpy.linspace(-1, 1, num=columns)):

        result[row_index, column_index] = mset(Re, Im, 200)

plt.figure(dpi=100)

plt.imshow(result.T, cmap='hot', interpolation='bilinear', extent=[-2, 1, -1, 1])

plt.xlabel('Real')

plt.ylabel('imagin')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Saudações, Vanderson; estamos no [pt.so], então poderia traduzir sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

O código em destaque na pergunta percorre um espaço no plano complexo para verificar se cada ponto pertence ou não ao conjunto de Mandelbrot.

Inicialmente, o código define um *array* para armazenar o resultado do teste de cada ponto no plano (na pergunta, definido com tamanho 2000x2000):

```
result = numpy.zeros([rows, columns])
```

Na seqüencia, existem 2 *loopings* que percorrem todo o espaço (real x imaginário).

O intervalo é definido pela função [`linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), que gera `num` números dentro desse intervalo:

```
# Looping da parte real, composto de 2000 samples no intervalo de -2.0 a 1.0
for row_index, Re in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-2, 1, num=rows)):

    # Looping da parte imaginária, composto de 2000 samples no intervalo de -1.0 a 1.0
    for column_index, Im in enumerate (numpy.linspace(-1, 1, num=columns)):
```

Os *loopings* vão gerar os pontos para teste.

Exemplo: `(-2.0,-1.0), (-2.0,-0.99)...(-1.99,-1.0),(-1.99,-0.99)...... até (1.0,1.0)`

Dentro do *looping* e para cada ponto, a função `mset` calcula se o ponto pertence ou não ao conjunto Mandelbrot e retorna o número de iterações necessárias para determinar essa pertinência.

Esse resultado é armazenado dentro do *array* `result`:

```
result[row_index, column_index] = mset(Re, Im, 200)
```

Os demais comandos plotam o resultado obtido e exibem o gráfico do *array* `result`:
[image: Fractal de Mandelbrot]

Apesar de mencionado na pergunta, esse programa não contempla conceitos de [orientação a objeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos).

Mais informações em: [Wikipedia - Conjunto de Mandelbrot](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto_de_Mandelbrot)

Comment: Muito obrigado, Gomiero, ajudou muito.

Comment: De nada!! Se a resposta foi útil, por favor marque [como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)